# The next prime is as far as possible

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many primes $p$, such that the least prime greater than $p$ is $p' = \prod\limits_{i \leq k} p_i + 1$ where $2 = p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_k = p$ lists all prime below $p$?

Comment: How about a couple of examples in order to make your question a little clearer and easier to read? You're asking if there are infinitely many primes, surely you have found a few...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $\Pi_{i\leq k}+1$?

Comment: No, by Bertrand's postulate.  $2$ is the largest with this property.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Probably $\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}p_i\right)+1$.

Comment: I guess there is a $p_i$ missing.

Comment: I think it would be easier to formulate this problem as "are there infinitely many $n$ such that $p_{n+1}=\prod_{i=1}^np_i+1$?"

Comment: @Slade : Perhaps you should post an answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Slade That's an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @JackM I was browsing briefly on my phone while giving a quiz, and only had time to type two dollar signs.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is on behalf of @Slade. Bertrand postulate also known as Tchebychev theorem states that for any integer $n\geq 2$ there exists at least one prime $n\leq p\leq 2n$.
therefore for any prime $p$ there exists a prime $q$ such that $$p\leq q\leq 2p\lt \prod_{p_i\leq p}p_i$$
so in essence what you are asking for never happens.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, except that $p = 2$ satisfies the condition given by the OP and it's the only one doing so.